# Automating SQL scripts in Toad for Oracle (13.1)

Tags: oracle, plsql, toad, automation

I'm not a DBA, so bear with me.

I've scheduled tasks through Toad's automation designer, but this uses Windows task scheduler. It's using Oracle 12c. All I'm doing is updating (creating/dropping) tables with the most recent data. Then I use an ODBC to report on that data in another application.

How can I ensure my scripts execute on time without running a local machine with scheduled tasks? Can this be done without additional software? Thanks in advance.

Comment: DBMS_SCHEDULER is your friend https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMIN/scheduse.htm https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/scheduler-10g

Comment: I would probably use `TRUNCATE TABLE` instead of `DROP TABLE`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> DBMS_SCHEDULER is your friend https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMIN/scheduse.htm 
>   and  https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/scheduler-10g – Philᵀᴹ Oct 21 at 19:11

Also, I recommend you use SQL Developer instead.  That software has a GUI interface for creating the scheduled jobs to run.

[image: SQLDeveloper Connections pane showing the Scheduler tree branch]